# how could the value of current_user be inserted into error logs/emails when using Flask-Login?

Tags: python, flask, logging, flask-login

I have the following code in my app factory...

```
mh = SMTPHandler(
    mailhost=app.config["MAIL_SERVER"],
    fromaddr=app.config["MAIL_DEFAULT_SENDER"],
    toaddrs=app.config["ERRORS_EMAIL"],
    subject="Error",
)
mh.setLevel(logging.ERROR)
app.logger.addHandler(mh)
```

Is there any way to get the value of "current_user" inserted into the email somewhere?

Comment: You may be looking for [LoggerAdapter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#loggeradapter-objects). Set the `Formatter` of your handler and then wrap the `Logger` object around the `LoggerAdapter` class: `mh.setFormatter(logging.Formatter('%(user)s - %(message)s')); app.logger = LoggerAdapter(app.logger, {'user': current_user})`.

Comment: This worked perfectly. If you want to write it up as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Adding contextual information](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html#context-info) to your logging output can be accomplished by wrapping your `Logger` object around a [`LoggerAdapter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#loggeradapter-objects) object and providing the extra information you wish to add. The following is an illustration:

```
mh = SMTPHandler(
    mailhost=app.config["MAIL_SERVER"],
    fromaddr=app.config["MAIL_DEFAULT_SENDER"],
    toaddrs=app.config["ERRORS_EMAIL"],
    subject="Error",
)
mh.setLevel(logging.ERROR)
mh.setFormatter(logging.Formatter('%(user)s - %(message)s'))
app.logger.addHandler(mh)
app.logger = LoggerAdapter(app.logger, {'user': current_user})
```

This should update the formatter of the `SMTPHandler` with the additional details, as well as convert `app.logger` to a `LoggerAdapter` object with extra information provided as a dictionary.

You may also find that [`Filter`s](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html#using-filters-to-impart-contextual-information) fit the bill in this case. They may also offer more dynamism, especially with values that are request specific. You can use one here by subclassing the `Filter` class and providing your own implementation of the `filter` method, which should update the record to be logged:

```
class CurrentUserFilter(logging.Filter):
    """
    Add a user attribute to all records
    """
    def filter(self, record):
        record.user = current_user
        return True  # Return True to pass the record to the next filter


mh = SMTPHandler(
    mailhost=app.config["MAIL_SERVER"],
    fromaddr=app.config["MAIL_DEFAULT_SENDER"],
    toaddrs=app.config["ERRORS_EMAIL"],
    subject="Error",
)
mh.setLevel(logging.ERROR)
mh.setFormatter(logging.Formatter('%(user)s - %(message)s'))
app.logger.addHandler(mh)
app.logger.addFilter(CurrentUserFilter())
```

This should add a `user` attribute to every log record, which sould, in turn, get picked up by the formatter.